# Compute address within XlsxWriter to avoid using INDIRECT(ADDRESS(...)) in formula?

Tags: excel-formula, xlsxwriter

I am writing a simple Excel report which has a formula referencing other cells (relative and row-absolute addresses).

I could achieve the goal with something like this:

```py
worksheet.write_formula(
    # Zero based:
    row,
    col,
    # One based:
    f'=INDIRECT(ADDRESS({row+1},{col+1},4,,"Counts"))/INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,{col+1},1))',
)
```

However, this is ugly and the Excel file has the clumsy `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(...))` function calls.

I would like to be able to pre-compute the address in Python, and use that directly in the formula.

Answer (score 2):

```py
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

worksheet.write_formula(
    # Zero based:
    row,
    col,
    # Also zero based:
    f'=Counts!{xl_rowcol_to_cell(row, col)}/{xl_rowcol_to_cell(1, col, True)}',
)
```

See https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html#xl-rowcol-to-cell